# Closest fraction

Tags: code-golf, math, number, rational-numbers, division

### Task:

Your program is given a [proper](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Proper_and_improper_fractions), positive [simple fraction](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Simple.2C_common.2C_or_vulgar_fractions) in the format `<numerator>/<denominator>`.

For this input, it must find two fractions.

1. A fraction that is less than the input.
2. A fraction that is greater than the input.

Both fractions must have a lower denominator than the input. Of all possible fractions, they should have the lowest difference to the input.

### Output:

Your program's output must be:

- A fraction that is smaller than the input, in the format `<numerator>/<denominator>`.
- Followed by a space character (ASCII-code 32).
- Followed by a fraction that is greater than the input, in the format `<numerator>/<denominator>`.

As follows:

```
«fraction that is < input» «fraction that is > input»
```

### Rules:

- All fractions outputted must be [in lowest terms](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction).
- All fractions outputted must be proper fractions.
- If there are no proper fractions possible that are allowed by the rules, you must output `0` instead of a fraction < input, and `1` instead of a fraction > input.
- You can choose whether you want to receive the fraction as a command-line argument (e.g. `yourprogram.exe 2/5`) or prompt for user input.
- You may assume your program won't receive invalid input.
- The shortest code (in bytes, in any language) wins.
- Any non-standard command-line arguments (arguments that aren't normally required to run a script) count towards the total character count.
- What your program **must not** do:

  - Depend on any external resources.
  - Depend on having a specific file name.
  - Output anything other than the required output.
  - Take exceptionally long to run. If your program runs over a minute for fractions with a 6-digit numerator and denominator (e.g. `179565/987657`) on an average home user's computer, it's invalid.
  - Output fractions with `0` as the denominator. You can't divide by zero.
  - Output fractions with `0` as the numerator. Your program must output `0` instead of a fraction.
  - Reduce an inputted fraction. If the fraction given as input is reducible, you must use the fraction as it is inputted.
- Your program must not be written in a programming language for which there did not exist a publicly available compiler / interpreter before this challenge was posted.

### Examples:

**Input:** `2/5`
**Output:** `1/3 1/2`

**Input:** `1/2`
**Output:** `0 1`

**Input:** `5/9`
**Output:** `1/2 4/7`

**Input:** `1/3`
**Output:** `0 1/2`

**Input:** `2/4`
**Output:** `1/3 2/3`

**Input:** `179565/987657`
**Output:** `170496/937775 128779/708320`

Comment: Your first example does not match the specification: *Both fractions must have a lower denominator than the input.*

Comment: First example, output should be `1/3 1/2`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek You're right. Fixed.

Comment: Could we have an example where the input is reducible? Oh, right.

Comment: Are `0/1` and `1/1` accepted if they replace `0` and `1` ?

Comment: @Michael `1/1` isn't a proper fraction. As for `0/1`, I hadn't realized that it is a proper fraction, so I've added a rule to say that isn't allowed.

Comment: If my language of choice uses double slashes to denote rationals, is that valid for input and output as well, or do they have to be single slashes?

Comment: Define "average home user's computer". Is 90 seconds on a 1.6GHz Intel Atom machine acceptable?

Comment: Are negative fractions allowed?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think that would be okay. I won't be too strict, if I think it's likely that it runs in about one minute on recent customer-grade hardware, I'll probably accept it (unless the chosen kind of computer isn't very common and vastly outperforms others). The reason for this rule was mainly to exclude brute-force solutions that take almost forever to complete.

Comment: @m.buettner I'd rather not make exceptions for specific programming languages. The rules will remain the same, even if that puts your language of choice at a disadvantage

Comment: @user80551 No, the rules explicitly state your program is given a proper, **positive** simple fraction in the format specified.

Comment: Your last example is incorrect.  The input fraction equals the first of the output fractions.

Comment: @David Oops, you're right. Fixed now (I hope). (Just in case I got it wrong again: I wrote [this piece](https://ideone.com/XiWQzt) of code to calculate the closest lower fraction. I am linking it here so people can see if there are any bugs in it.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this means all the answers are wrong as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sage – <s>119</s> 117

```python
x,X=map(int,raw_input().split('/'))
a=0
A=c=C=1
while C<X:exec("ab,,AB"[c*X>C*x::2]+"=c,C");c=a+b;C=A+B
print a/A,b/B
```

Sage is only needed in the last line, which takes care of the output. Everything else also works in Python.

Replace `raw_input()` with `sys.argv[1]` to have the input read from a command-line argument instead of a prompt. This does not change the character count. (Does not work in Python without importing `sys` first.)

This essentially recursively constructs the respective [Farey sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) using mediants of the existing elements, but restricts itself to those elements closest to the input. From another point of view, it runs a nested-interval search on the respective Farey sequences.

It correctly processes all of the examples in less than a second on my machine.

Here is an ungolfed version:

```python
x,X = map(Integer,sys.argv[1].split('/'))
x = x/X
a = 0
c = b = 1
while c.denominator() < X:
    if c > x:
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    c = ( a.numerator() + b.numerator() ) / ( a.denominator() + b.denominator() )
print a,b
```

Comment: I was already afraid that I wouldn't get any new submissions for this bounty. Great work.

Comment: Nice trick with the `exec`!

Comment: As the only answer submitted within the bounty period, I am hereby awarding you the bounty. Congratulations.

Comment: I just [fixed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction/39919#comment126793_26278) an [error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction/39919#comment115348_26278) in one of the examples. You may want to correct your submission (even though it's been half a year since you submitted it).

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2.7 - 138

```python
x,y=n,d=map(int,raw_input().split('/'))
while y:x,y=y,x%y
def f(p,a=d):
 while(a*n+p)%d:a-=1
 print`(a*n+p)/d`+('/'+`a`)*(a>1),
f(-x);f(x)
```

I started with the obvious brute-force solution, but I realized that since the OP wanted to be able to solve instances with six digit numerators and denominators in under a minute, I need a better solution than trying a trillion possibilities. I found a handy formula on the Wikipedia page for the Farey sequence: If a/b, c/d are neighbors in one of the Farey sequences, with `a/b<c/d`, then `b*c-a*b=1`. The while loop inside f in my program extends this fact to non-reduced numbers, using the gcd, which the other while loop calculates.

I've golfed this pretty hard already, but I'd love to hear any suggestions.

### Edits:

166->162: Removed `a` and `b` from the outer program. They were unnecessary.
162->155: `str()` -> ``
155->154: Added `k`.
154->152: Removed `x` from inside the function, passed it as an argument instead.
152->150: Gave `a` a default value instead of passing it as an argument.
150->146: Changed the initialization of `x` and `y`.
146->145: Removed `k`.
145->144: Changed ... and ... or ... to (...,...)[...], thereby saving a space.
144->138: Changed (...,...)[...] to ...+...*(...). Thanks to @mbomb007.

### Test cases:

```
2/5
1/3 1/2

1/2
0 1

2/4
1/3 2/3

179565/987657
170496/937775 128779/708320

12345678/87654321
12174209/86436891 11145405/79132382
```

The second to last test took under a second on my computer, while the last one took about 5-10 seconds.

Comment: This `k=1` is pure wickedness.

Comment: @Evpok: I was trying to get k=y=n to work, but apparently if you modify a variable inside a function, python wants it to be local. This was the only way to get a local variable in 4 characters. Also, since the fraction is positive and proper, the denominator can't be 1.

Comment: Command-line arguments are easy with Python, so they should have been used for input as instructed here.

Comment: "**You can choose** whether you want to receive the fraction as a command-line argument (e.g. yourprogram.exe 2/5) **or prompt for user input**."

Comment: Save 6 chars: ``print`(a*n+p)/d`+('/'+`a`)*(a>1),``

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 163 bytes

```
{a,b}=FromDigits/@InputString[]~StringSplit~"/";r=Range[b-1];""<>Riffle[#~ToString~InputForm&/@(#@DeleteCases[#2[a/b*r]/r,a/b]&@@@{{Max,Floor},{Min,Ceiling}})," "]
```

This is severely limited by the input/output requirement as user input and strings. Dealing with strings is really cumbersome in Mathematica (at least when you want to golf). Doing this the natural way in Mathematica, (using just integers and rationals) I'd probably get this down to 50% of the size.

It can do 6-digit numbers in a few seconds on my machine.

Slightly more readable (not really ungolfed though):

```
{a, b} = FromDigits /@ InputString[]~StringSplit~"/";
r = Range[b - 1];
"" <> Riffle[#~ToString~
     InputForm & /@ (#[DeleteCases[#2[a/b*r]/r, a/b]] & @@@ {{Max, 
       Floor}, {Min, Ceiling}}), " "]
```

For the fun of it, doing this "the natural way", i.e. as a function taking numerator and denominator and returning two rationals, this is only **84 characters** (so my 50% estimate was actually pretty close):

```
f[a_,b_]:=#@DeleteCases[#2[a/b*(r=Range[b-1])]/r,a/b]&@@@{{Max,Floor},{Min,Ceiling}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia - <s>127</s> 125 bytes

I've approached this from a mathematical perspective to avoid need for loops, so this code runs quite fast for large inputs (note: if a/b is the input, then a*b must fit within Int64 (Int32 on 32 bit systems), otherwise nonsense answers are generated - if a and b are both expressible in Int32 (Int16 on 32 bit systems), no problems occur).

UPDATE: There's no longer a need to overload backslash for div, by using ÷, a net saving 2 bytes.

```julia
a,b=int(split(readline(),"/"));k=gcd(a,b);f=b-invmod(a÷k,b÷k);d=2b-f-b÷k;print(a*d÷b,d<2?" ":"/$d ",a*f÷b+1,"/$f"^(f>1))
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
a,b=int(split(readline(),"/")) # Read in STDIN in form a/b, convert to int
k=gcd(a,b)           # Get the greatest common denominator
f=b-invmod(a÷k,b÷k)  # Calculate the denominator of the next biggest fraction
d=2b-f-b÷k           # Calculate the denominator of the next smallest fraction
print(a*d÷b,d<2?" ":"/$d ",a*f÷b+1,"/$f"^(f>1)) # Calculate numerators and print
```

Basic idea: find the largest d and f less than b that satisfies ad-bc=gcd(a,b) (next smallest) and be-af=gcd(a,b) (next largest), then calculate c and e from there. Resulting output is c/d e/f, unless either d or f is 1, in which case the /d or /f is omitted.

Interestingly, this means that the code also works for positive improper fractions, so long as the input is not an integer (that is, gcd(a,b)=a).

On my system, inputting `194857602/34512958303` takes no perceivable time to output `171085289/30302433084 23772313/4210525219`

Comment: Testing with `55552/999999` gives me `-396/920632 486/936509`.

Comment: @user2428118 - Are you on a 32 bit system (or using a 32 bit Julia)? I've used "int", which means that on a 32 bit system, it'll use Int32 rather than Int64. `int32(55552*999999)` gives `-282630400`. For me, with that test, I get `51143/920632 52025/936509` - note that the denominators are the same, and that 52025-51143 = 486-(-396). I'll add a note to mention this issue.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the code will work for all Int64 size inputs, you can replace "int" with "int128". With that change, inputting `1234567891234567/2145768375829475878` results in `869253326028691/1510825213275018197 365314565205876/634943162554457681`. This change adds just 3 extra characters.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a 32-bit computer. I'll try it on a 64-bit machine sometime when I've got the time for it.

Comment: Testing on a 64-bit computer gives the correct result, so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 131

With fat arrow notation and `eval` calls :

```js
m=>{for(e=eval,n=e(m),i=p=0,q=1;++i</\d+$/.exec(m);)if(n*i>(f=n*i|0))g=f+1,p=f/i>e(p)?f+'/'+i:p,q=g/i<e(q)?g+'/'+i:q;return p+' '+q}
```

The `179565/987657` stress test is executed in approximately **35 seconds** on Firefox, a lot more on Chrome (~ 6 minutes)

Faster method and without `eval` and fat arrow notation

```js
for(n=eval(m=prompt(a=i=p=0,b=c=d=q=1));++i<m.match(/\d+$/);)if(n*i>(f=n*i|0))g=f+1,p=f*c>i*a?(a=f)+'/'+(c=i):p,q=g*d<i*b?(b=g)+'/'+(d=i):q;alert(p+' '+q)
```

The `179565/987657` stress test is executed in approximately 5 seconds.

Not golfed :

```js
m=prompt(); //get input
a=0; c=1; //first fraction
b=1; d=1; //second fraction
n=eval(m); //evaluate input
for (i=1; i<m.match(/\d+$/); i++) { //loop from 1 to input denominator
  f=Math.floor(n*i);
  if (n*i > f) { //if fraction not equal to simplification of input
    g=f+1; // f/i and g/i are fractions closer to input
    if (f/i>a/c) a=f, c=i;
    if (g/i<b/d) b=g; d=i; 
  }
}
alert(a+'/'+c+' '+b+'/'+d); //output values handling 0 and 1 correctly
```

Comment: too... much... `eval`. EEK

Comment: Testing with `2/6` gives `1/3 2/5`, however `1/3` is not **less than** but **equal to** `2/6`.

Comment: @user2428118 fixed

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted so early?

Comment: @user2428118: You know, you can allow a couple days to pass before accepting solutions. Also, this solution is no longer the shortest.

Comment: @isaacg I'll change the accepted answer when a shorter solution becomes available. The JavaScript answer is now shorter, though.

Comment: On a second thought, accepting an answer already may discourage people from posting. I'll wait, then.

Comment: Save two bytes: `m=>{for(e=eval,n=e(m),i=p=0,q=1;++i</\d+$/.exec(m);n*i>f&&(g=f+1,p=f/i>e(p)?f+'/'+i:p,q=g/i<e(q)?g+'/'+i:q))f=n*i|0;return p+' '+q}`

Comment: @nderscore, thanks for the regex reduction but the `&&` trick seems to not work.

Comment: Your ungolfed code is broken.

Comment: I just [fixed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction/39919#comment126793_26278) an [error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction/39919#comment115348_26278) in one of the examples. You may want to correct your submission (even though it's been a year since you submitted it).

Answer (score 2):

## perl, 142 bytes (155 without CPAN)

```
use bare A..Z;$/="/";N=<>;D=<>;F=N/D;K=G=1;for$H(1..D){J<F&&J>E?(E,I):J>F&&J<G?(G,K):()=(J=$_/H,"$_/$H")for(Z=int F*H)..Z+1}print I||0," $K\n"
```

Or if CPAN modules are disallowed / 3-4 times faster code is needed:

```
$/="/";$N=<>;$D=<>;$F=$N/$D;$g=$G=1;for$d(1..$D){$f<$F&&$f>$E?($E,$e):$f>$F&&$f<$G?($G,$g):()=($f=$_/$d,"$_/$d")for($z=int$F*$d)..$z+1}print$e||0," $g\n"
```

The former version takes 9.55 seconds on my machine, the latter version 2.44 seconds.

Less unreadable:

```
($N, $D) = split(m[/], <>);
$F = $N / $D;
$G = 1;
foreach $d (1 .. $D) {
    $z = int $F * $d;
    foreach $_ ($z .. $z + 1) {
        $f = $_ / $d;
        ($f < $F && $f > $E ? ($E, $e) :
        ($f > $F && $f < $G ? ($G, $g) : ())) = ($f, "$_/$d");
    }
}
print $e || 0, ' ', $g || 1, "\n";
```