# Find the simplest value between two values

Tags: code-golf, math, binary, rational-numbers

### Goal

Your goal is to find the *simplest* value in an open interval. In other words, given two values `a,b` with `a<b`, output the simplest `x` with `a<x<b`. This is a code golf, so fewest bytes wins.

### Simplicity

All values in this problem are [dyadic rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), which means their binary expansions are finite, or equivalently, are rationals in simplest form `a/2^b` for some integer `a` and non-negative integer `b`. Integers are dyadic rationals with `b=0`.

Being *simpler* means having smaller `b`, tiebroken by smaller absolute value `|a|`.

Equivalently in terms of binary expansions, to find the simpler number:

1. Take the one with a shorter fractional part (fewer binary digits after the point).
2. In case of tie, take the lexicographically earlier one with length the primary sort, ignoring sign.

So, the numbers in simplicity order are

```
0, ±1, ±2, ±3, ±4, ...
±1/2, ±3/2, ±5/2, ...
±1/4, ±3/4, ±5/4, ...
±1/8, ±3/8, ... 
±1/16, ...
...
```

There's no need to say which of `±x` is simpler because any interval that contains both candidates also contains `0`, which is simpler than both.

(A bit of background and motivation: In [combinatorial game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory), positions in a two-player games have a numerical value representing magnitude of advantage, with the sign saying which player is favored. This value is determined recursively from the two values resulting from the best move of each player. You might guess that one averages them, but in fact it's the simplest value in between.)

### Program requirements

Write, in as few bytes as possible, a *program* or *named function* that takes two dyadic rationals `a,b` and outputs the simplest dyadic rational `x` with `a<x<b`. Input can be function input or STDIN, and output can be function return or printing.

**Input format**

Two dyadic rationals `a,b` in whatever type your languages use for real or finite-precision binary values (float, double, etc). Fraction or rational types that store the value as a numerator and denominator are not acceptable. If you language has no valid type (and only then), you may use binary strings like `101.1101`, or post a comment and we'll work something out.

You are guaranteed that `a,b` are dyadic rationals and `a<b`. Integer values will be given like `3.0`, not `3`.

You can assume you have sufficient precision to store the values, the output, and any intermediate steps exactly. So, you shouldn't worry about precision or overflows. I won't give an explicit bound on inputs, but your algorithm should take a reasonable amount of time on inputs like the test cases.

You may take your two numbers in any reasonable built-in container like pair, tuple, list, array, or set. Structures specifically representing intervals are not allowed though.

**Output**

The simplest dyadic rational strictly between `a` and `b`. The same rules for the input types apply, except outputting `3` rather than `3.0` is OK.

**Test cases**

```
(-1.0, 1.0)
0.0
(0.0, 2.0)
1.0
(0.0, 4.0)
1.0
(0.5, 2.0)
1.0
(-3.25, -2.5)
-3.0
(-4, 1.375)
0.0
(4.5, 4.625)
4.5625
(-1.875, -1.5)
-1.75
```

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26278/8478

Comment: @MartinBüttner "Fraction or rational types that store the value as a numerator and denominator are not acceptable." But if your rational type is just real numbers stored internally as rational for exact precision and you don't use things like `.get_denom()`, it's OK. Also, the output should be not be written in fraction form.

Comment: Ugh, it's getting late and my attention span is apparently dwindling...

Comment: Probably should specify that there is at least one representable value between *a* and *b*.

Comment: @feersum How would that fail to be the case?

Comment: Assuming the number is stored in a fixed-precision floating-point format, there is a finite number of possible values. It is possible to choose two numbers that are adjacent to each other in the list of all representable values.

Comment: @feersum Thanks. I though this would be handled by "You can assume you have sufficient precision to store the value exactly," but that doesn't guarantee the output can be represented. Will edit.

Comment: I posted a discussion question on meta to gather opinion on how to treat machine limits in code golf specs and answers http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2280/20260

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2 - 100

I think I revised my entire method for this answer a good 4 or 5 times (which is probably an indication that it's a good code-golf question). I don't know if this answer can be golfed down any more but I do feel as if I'm missing some more clever methodological ways to shorten this.

```py
def f(a,b,i=1.):
    r=0if a<0 else(a*i+1)//1/i
    return-f(-b,-a,i)if b<=0 else r if r<b else f(a,b,i*2)
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work for large-magnitude numbers. Note that `x + 1` may be equal to `x`, if `x` is greater than `2**53`.

Comment: I didn't intend for overflows or representation limits to be a concern. I've edited to make that clear.

Comment: How is that an overflow? It's only the result of an approach that doesn't work.

Comment: @feersum "You can assume you have sufficient precision to store the values, the output, and any intermediate steps exactly." Is that not sufficient?

Comment: OK, I see you have edited it just now. I prefer the non-watered down version. Or maybe I will make one that uses the intermediate step of adding 2^-1074 until the answer is reached:)

Comment: @feersum I had also added "your algorithm should take a reasonable amount of time on inputs like the test cases" in anticipation of that :-P

Comment: @feersum You bring up an interesting point, but you could argue with inputs `a = 2**53` and `b = 2**53 + 4` for example, the desired answer mathematically would be 2**53 + 1 (not 2**53 + 2) which I am representing as close as possible with 2**53. It raises the question of whether it is preferable to have the output strictly greater than the lower bound, or to have the output be (potentially) as close to the mathematically correct answer as possible. In any case I suppose it's moot now that the question has been revised so that precision is a non-issue.

Comment: These types of ambiguities are interesting and have come up many times before, so I posted a discussion question on meta to gather opinions on how to treat machine limits in code golf specs and answers http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2280/20260

Comment: Sorry for such a trivial golf, but you can save a character by using `(a*i+1)//1/i` and removing the space after the `else`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Every character counts :P

Comment: Remove the space between `r=0` and `if` to save one byte

Comment: @ace I have absolutely no idea why python accepts this as valid syntax. Is it unintentional? I can't think of any reason for it to be implemented. It doesn't even work with other keywords like the `else`.

Comment: @KSab I don't know why it works either... I just saw it here once and used it ever since

Comment: @kSab You can generally have a keyword right after a number because the number is parse as its own unit. But something like `3else` starts to parse as scientific notation like `3e4` and fails.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>61</s> <s>88</s> <s>75</s> 73

```
p!q|p<0= -(-q)!(-p)|r<q=max r 0|0<1=(2*p)!(2*q)/2where r=toEnum$floor$p+1
```

this checks if there is a whole number between the two, and if yes, return the smallest one. if not, multiply the numbers by 2, apply them recursively, divide by 2 and return.
at least, this is how it works in my mind. the actual code is a bit different.

thanks to xnor for his rounding magic

Comment: I don't think this works for ranges that contain `0`. Trying `-3!4` gives `-3.5`, instead of `0`. I think you may be assuming that the inputs have the same sign, although, I admit I don't know much about Haskell, am I doing something wrong? (and sorry, if I am)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman negatives in Haskell are a bit annoying. `-3!4` is parsed as `-(3!4)`, which should be -3.5. but you are infact right, `(-3)!4` is `-2.0`. I'll fix it when i can

Comment: Ah, thanks for that tip :) You might be able to try multiplying (or just returning?) your result by `0` if `p*q<0`. Again, don't know much about Haskell, but that is usually a good way to check for having different signs.

Answer (score 1):

### Java - <s>157</s> <s>187</s> 186

Probably could be golfed more.

Thanks to Quincunx for a byte.

```
void f(float a,float b){for(float i=1,d;;i*=2){for(d=0;d<i*Math.max(Math.abs(b),Math.abs(a));d++){for(float x:new float[]{d/i,-d/i}){if(x<b&&x>a){System.out.print(x);System.exit(0);}}}}}
```

Brute forces all values of the numerator (positive and negative) while the denominator doubles each time.

Comment: I don't think imports are free.

Comment: This doesn't work for large values either. E.g. if I call `f((float)1e30, (float)1e31)` it appears to go into an infinite loop. Or was I just not patient enough?

Comment: I edited the rules to not worry about precision or representation issues. Floats are fine.

Comment: @ypnypn This is an issue that comes in Java in that you can't do imports without wrapping the function in a class. Here's what I say: You can have a "floating" import statement separate from the function, but the chars in the import statement count, including a char for newline. So this is 189 chars.

Comment: @feersum you probably aren't patient enough :)

Comment: 186 chars: `void f(float a,float b){for(float i=1,d;;i*=2){for(d=0;d<i*Math.max(Math.abs(b),Math.abs(a));d++){for(float x:new float[]{d/i,-d/i}){if(x<b&&x>a){System.out.print(x);System.exit(0);}}}}}`. Avoiding importing saves it, and you would have needed the static imports. The stuff in the `java.lang` package are automatically "imported"

Answer (score 1):

## C, 98 bytes

Using a recursive algorithm (and the fact that f(a,b) = f(2*a,2*b)/2).
I also removed some bugs. The right answer is:

```
float n(float a, float b){return (floor(a+1)<ceil(b))?(a<0?(b>0?0:ceil(b-1)):floor(a+1)):n(2*a,2*b)/2;}
```

Which, to meet the prerequisites, is 19 bytes longer than the original one (of 79 bytes)

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float n(float a, float b){return (floor(a+1)<ceil(b))?(a<0?(b>0?0:ceil(b-1)):floor(a+1)):n(2*a,2*b)/2;}
main() 
{
    float a = -4.0;
    float b = -1.4;
    printf("%f",n(a,b));
}
```

Just copy-paste it into [a random online c compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) and run it.

Comment: Does this give f(-4, 1.375)=0.0? I don't see the code handling that case.

Comment: `a` and `b` seem to be reversed, and I think you may have misread the question a bit. `n(2.1,1.2)` gives me `3.0` instead of `1.5`, and any integer input, like `n(2.0,1.0)` will crash because `ceil(a)>a` is always false.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman but the spec tells to assume that the first parameter is smaller

Comment: Does this work on negatives? Your code chooses the smallest whole number in the range, so for example on -7.5, -3.5 this would choose -7 when the result should be -4

Comment: @proudhaskeller That is correct, but this code will only exit the recursion when `ciel(a)>ciel(b)`, which will never happen if `a`, the first parameter, is smaller than `b`. Also, for `-3.5,-7.5` this code returns `-3.0`, the ceiling of the larger number.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman yes, because you switched the parameters around. I believe he meant to write `ceil(a)<ceil(b)`.

Comment: @Gerwin when are you going to fix this?

Comment: @proudhaskeller It should be fixed.

Comment: @GerwinDox From reading the code, I still don't see how it would give `n(-4, 1.375)=0.0`. Have you checked the test cases? I wasn't able to actually test your code because I don't know C; if you could link to an online running version, that would help.

Comment: Apparently now, 0 is worth more than 1. Ugh. I had to add 19 bytes to keep it running.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl (89)

most probably this can still be golfed

```perl
sub S{($q,$w)=@_;$m=1,$r=0;until($q<$r&&$r<$w){$r=int$q+1;$r<$w||map$_*=2,$m,$q,$w}$r/$m}
```

Comment: In perl 5.32 (released in June 2020) comparison operators can be chained. This means that you can replace `$q<$r&&$r<$w` with `$q<$r<$w` and save four bytes. https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlop.pod#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3: 80 bytes

```python
g=lambda a,b:-g(-b,-a)if b<=0 else int(a+1)*(a>=0)if-~int(a)<b else g(2*a,2*b)/2
```

Ungofed:

```python
def g(a,b):
    if b<=0:return -g(-b,-a)
    if int(a+1)<b:return int(a+1)*(a>=0)
    return g(2*a,2*b)/2
```

Can probably be golfed more by changing the `if/else` structure to `and/or`. The obvious transformation fails due to non-short-circuiting on the Falsey output of `0`, but there's likely a rearrangement that does it.

The space in `b<=0 else` can't be removed as usual because the start letter `e` is parsed as part of number literals like `1e6`.

Comment: can I port your code?

Comment: @proudhaskeller Definitely.

Answer (score 1):

## ES6, <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 59

```
g=(a,b)=>(x=~~(a+1),b>0?x<b?x*(x>0):g(2*a,2*b)/2:-g(-b,-a))
```

this is a port of xnor's solution (basically, the new thing in it was that it checked for having `0` in the range by `*(a>=0)`. couldn't do this in Haskell because Haskell has a type system :) )

this is the first time I used ES6 ever, so this might still be golfable.

Comment: For the type issue of `x*(a>=0)`, an alternative is `max(x,0)`. Can you do that efficiently in Haskell?

Comment: @xnor your rounding magic is ingenious

Comment: Also, you can do `x*(x>0)`. I couldn't do that in Python because I can't assign `x`.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I believe `~~(a+1)` is the same as `-~a`, saving 4 bytes. Also, with some rearrangement, you can save another 3 bytes: `g=(a,b)=>b>0?-~a<b?-~a*(~a<0):g(2*a,2*b)/2:-g(-b,-a)`