# Surreal Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, rational-numbers, set-theory

[Surreal Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) are one way of describing numbers using sets. In this challenge you will determine the value of a surreal number.

## Intro

A surreal number consists of two sets: a left and right. The value of the surreal number must be greater than all numbers in the left set and less than all numbers in the right set. We define 0 as having nothing in each set, which we write as `{|}`. Each surreal number also has a birth date. 0 is born on day 0. On each successive day, new surreal numbers are formed by taking the numbers formed on previous days and placing them in the left/right sets of a new number. For example, `{0|} = 1` is born on day 1, and `{|0} = -1` is also born on day 1.

To determine the value of a surreal number, we find the number "between" the left and right sets that was born earliest. As a general rule of thumb, numbers with lower powers of 2 in their denominator are born earlier. For example, the number `{0|1}` (which is born on day 2 by our rules) is equal to `1/2`, since 1/2 has the lowest power of 2 in its denominator between 0 and 1. In addition, if the left set is empty, we take the largest possible value, and vice versa if the right set is empty. For example, `{3|} = 4` and `{|6} = 5`.

*Note that `4` and `5` are just symbols that represent the surreal number, which just happen to align with our rational numbers if we define operations in a certain way.*

Some more examples:

```
{0, 1|} = {1|} = {-1, 1|} = 2
{0|3/4} = 1/2
{0|1/2} = 1/4
{0, 1/32, 1/16, 1/2 |} = 1
```

## Input

A list/array of two lists/arrays, which represent the left and right set of a surreal number. The two lists/arrays will be sorted in ascending order and contain either dyadic rationals (rationals with denominator of 2^n) or other surreal numbers.

## Output

A dyadic rational in either decimal or fraction form representing the value of the surreal number.

## Examples

```
Input -> Output
[[], []] -> 0
[[1], []] -> 2
[[], [-2]] -> -3
[[0], [4]] -> 1
[[0.25, 0.5], [1, 3, 4]] -> 0.75
[[1, 1.5], [2]] -> 1.75
[[1, [[1], [2]]], [2]] -> 1.75
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Comment: Isn't 0 always born the earliset, since it's born on day 0?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Yes, but 0 isn't always within the bounds of the left and right set.

Comment: What does "between" the two sets mean?

Comment: And for the last example, is the [[1],[2]] a surreal number? If so, do we evaluate the value of surreal numbers inside the set first, then use the values as regular rational integers to find the value of the outside surreal number?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance For your second comment: yes, that's correct on both counts.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance "Between" means greater than all members of the left set and less than all members of the right set.

Comment: Can I take the input as a string, since I don't get how to implement the surreal numbers in the arrays thing? (Since hypothetically, those surreal numbers can have surreal numbers which in turn have more surreal numbers in them...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87818/discussion-between-quintec-and-embodiment-of-ignorance). @EmbodimentofIgnorance

Comment: `{|6}` Should be 0, not 5, in the real surreal numbers.

Comment: Closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38425/25180. Maybe a duplicate. The only difference (if fixed) is this challenge uses sets. But they don't add much for finite numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/), <s>228</s> <s>197</s> 184 bytes

Thanks to @LyricLy and friends for helping me golf this down a lot

`1e999` stolen from @Quintec's solution

```python
m=1e999
g=lambda p:[f(*x)if[]==x*0else x for x in p]
def f(l,h):
 h=min(g(h+[m]));l=max(g(l+[-m]));s=1
 while h-l<=1:l*=2;h*=2;s*=2
 return-(-h//1+1)/s if h<=0else l*h>=0and(l//1+1)/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3BToUwEEX3/YpZtkDlVTQR3ht/pOkCQ/vaZCgNYISvx4pxY6Kbk9w592bSvvopNjLtaT@OEZVt25bdkfrxbeghddrxYhPBaYO4FRdLi4UN3DRnhgjJsME6cJwqLzoGHscQ@Z37Uo9GiCvh2G85U6nleVhQMfjwgSx4STdUHRX4ePVfWDIYzHZ9n6Pk0te1KpWoFwgO/A2/n1PhX/HSx4HTjz/SHOLKHU19JtdNpXVjKv1kzEkhBPtVkS/ZPP9pZPOPejh3xyc)

Comment: I can't get this code running and producing the correct results... do you have a TIO link?

Comment: Added a tio.run link now, sorry for forgetting to do that

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>371</s> <s>362</s> <s>261</s> <s>251</s> <s>248</s> <s>241</s> <s>236</s> <s>234</s> 231 bytes

*-122 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only*

```python
def f(s):
 if s<[]:return s
 a=map(f,s[1]+[1e999,-1e999]+s[0]);m,n,u=a[-1],a[0],1
 while n-m<=1:m*=2;n*=2;u/=2.
 x,y=abs(m)-1,abs(n)-1;s=m>0>n or m<0<n;r=[[m-x*s,m+x*s][m<0]+1,[n-y*s,n+y*s][n<0]-1][x>y];return u*int([0,r][`r`<"m"])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/dboIwFIDveYoTr0BOWYuwiVBf5KSJLINoslbTSiZPz1pntgxddnN68n3nr6fxvD@afJreuh762CWbCA49uIbUxnbnwRpwEbRSt6e4R0dCpSS6qqqQXR@VOuIqqTUaHGRLTChsPUERwcf@8N6BYbqRYqOXMq9NCMOTzLMILjjK9tXFOmECQ2J8Ujupt3xr4GhBN7wxtZVEml2WDnXqoyKPVSqQDBs9NOkYoPHQr6bLdlT17e5heTDnmDhaRTu7axZ6oZLpZAPtYyKFpFSSRD@EZf568uE39hDmpQGxfAZ5oMV8aBEon5dmeYnAszJIgbBCmDd6Kr58fm9uV3nzqICt/T/KO1i8ZKW/htarIiufZ/oK/5JM/O2q6jZW8Iet32vZ@j8fsqCnTw)

Comment: Fail on `[[-8],[5]]` I guess, though I don't knows what it is

Comment: Yeah, invalid. Probably should be `0`?

Comment: [half fixed](https://tio.run/##Zc3BjsIgEIDhe59ijlAHLawedPVJJhyabFmbOLShkKwXX71CNJqtx/n@YRiv8Tx4M88uDAzcxjP0PA4h1tVP58CJSR4q6B1MR7KH0MUUPEwVMPoTt3@C1L7b2xW3o3A4UWOlRO69oH@sM1eQTqaub6rk3kdxGX6FV4wmP9Hy@3GbUq1upfImSUx5vQw@D5b42Nh5DAWcILJIttx9i7YISyukzAKbotslrs0OoVnvStQIXwjLlaz60c1nef6fy2thvgM)

Comment: [there we go](https://tio.run/##bY/LboMwEEX3fMUsbTKmhkAb0tAfGXlBRdwgdQziIbWb/Dq1S9SqpKuRz7lj3ek/p0vnsmWxQ8fA9XSBlvtumOKoOVuwYpTHCFoL44nMcThP8@BgjIDRVVx/CFLluTQ7rnthcSRtpERunaA/OPU4gqaioOrXUbDEMJyUKkVtSPBJy6oSzo9uEPyyvvwwEcxVFsdhs3WTeO/ehFOM2boqn9dONMfqGjyxapB3jSH/pXmYJc7xVX0b540Lxq1mjSz9EKwVRAbJhKa/JDUIWxaQyjZQB5pvoMoD1dtokhUIOimCTBH2CNtFT9PVZ/fm1sqb/wLq4K8o7mD@lBS@DR32eVI8bnRZ3myqf/TyBQ), now to golf it

Comment: Still invalid though, only works up to 9e9 in either direction, unless you change the spec to, say, require only up to the limits of a float32 or float64

Comment: [removed log](https://tio.run/##hY/BboMwDIbvPIUvkxKasITCVjrCi0Q5MAEq0uJWULTt0ldncdupEu20Sxx9n239Pnwfd3tM57lpO@jYyLcR9B2MpXXboT1OA8IYgRcoJuPrL@brA@uElUVbuNVoleNc@B5/@RVrwjqCz13/0QJWHmpsGEp80lwyL32opdFbH5v0DemZnk2aRNAYS9vq95F5Lqgg51IL5awvjaoMwn4AXxlVGnQRXCLaKZanHo/MetkIv2qoO0QTU3ySZ46BI3EkftHzYSDXMWudsC5Ejm5EOwFLRkimC6iIZgsoM6Jq2ZqkuQCV5CS1gLWA5WCg@uLTe3NNFcyjBrkJV@R3MHtN8pDGbtZZkr8s9Bn@JYviOqrVI31bLTf/efqRnn8A)

Comment: [works up to float limit](https://tio.run/##hY9db4MgFIbv/RXEK2jBgdWuX/SPEC5cLKlJOW1Qs@3XO07ttsy22Q2Q5znv6/Hy2R3PkA9DfXDE0ZZtEtJodzpXHU0bcCnbNo60O2M34dD1AUibEM@B99pXH9RXF@q4EY2dt0Zaxrhv4JteoUKoEvJ@bE4HAsLvtNr4mc63gEf/ovMsIbU2GKzeWuoZxwsYE4pLa2JA7jWQcyB@r@VOg90GbYwXNffzGgeknStuIAJAABEIZc3Yth/bYmjcv5810FETsLvtAg1M6xQqSC0bLgGdo8ZYbmzcPPklIlMRxuMvjpBMRxGJfAIl0mJaWiCV09EsLzmRWYlScbLgZBqMVI0@vze3raJ5NCBW8T/KO1i8ZmXcxqwWRVYuJ/oKn0mhnrv1@lar5MPoz2fF6j@PL9TDFw)

Comment: @ASCII-only Wow thanks so much

Comment: @Quintec Gotta make sure that's what you want it to do though

Comment: also... The two lists/arrays will be sorted in ascending order? [then you can do this](https://tio.run/##hY9NbsMgEEb3PgXyChJwwbXb/JGLjFi4clCQwiTCtqqe3oU4alUnUTeA3pv5mLl89cczluPYHiyxtGObjDhtT@emp7lDm7Ots6TbgdmEQz8EJF1GPEc@aN9cqOUgnFl2IA0DoQy/wStTkUnDVUY@j@50ICj8TquNX@hyi@kYXnRZZKTV4B3S5qOjnvF0IWNCcWkgNsi9RnIOxO@13Gk026ABvGi5X7apQJql4oARYAIYQRwEprT9lBabpuGHhcOeQkjZXR9oYFrn2GBu2HgJyVkKYDgYw1j2S0QRd4N4/MURknlpQqKcQZloNQ@tEpXz0qKsOZFFnaTi5JWTeWOkavLlvblNFc2jArGKe9R3sHov6jgNrF6ron6b6St8JoV67tbrW6ySD1t/vhWr/3x6JT1@Aw) (wait. is it broken

Comment: [fixed](https://tio.run/##hY/dbsIwDEbv@xRRrxrqdEnXbkAbXsSKRKdSUYkY1B8Nnr5LBtq0AtpNEp3z2bFPl2F/pHSa6l3Dmqjn64C1DetLNOtuN4wdsd4R3RyO1RCFLTUhLywQjNpWp6gBFK2Je5SGo1AGrrBHZWJsHZMGVMA@9@1hx0jYUqu1Xei0IH@MLzpNAnaGi64@@shy8BfxotZoW4qc4EKBNOgK5UYTO3bMbrQsNZmi04hW1GDj2gekiRUgOUAekANuIDxvLi563WRctDREKKEzuO22ZUgVhYZPp87zJkI0gMZwHvwSkbit0B1/sYNsHvVIpDMoPc3mTTNP5TyapDkwmeReKmCvwOaFjqqrT@/NbSpnHgXE0u2R38HsPcndNLh8zZL8baa/4TMp1HO3Wt3aKvmw9OdbsfzP@5fX0xc)

Comment: @ASCII-only yer a wizard

Comment: [248](https://tio.run/##hY/dbsIwDEbv@xRRrxrqdEnXbkAbXsSKRKdSUYkY1B8Nnr5LBtq0AtpNEp3z2bFPl2F/pHSa6l3Dmqjn64C1DetLNOtuN4wdsd4R3RyO1RCFLTUhLyptq1PUQI/KxNiCaE3cozS8sEAw6gqFMlA5Aipgn/v2sGMkbKnV2i50WpA/xhedJgE7w0VXH31kOfiLeFFrtC1FTnChQBp0hXKjiR07ZjdalppM0WlEK2qwce0D0sQKkBwgD8gBNwKeNxcXva4xLloaIpTQGdx22zKkikLDp1PneRMhGkBjOA9@iUjcHuiOv9hBNo96JNIZlJ5m86aZp3IeTdIcmExyLxWwV2DzQkfV1af35jaVM48CYun2yO9g9p7kbhpcvmZJ/jbT3/CZFOq5W61ubZV8WPrzrVj@5/3L6@kL)

Comment: [241](https://tio.run/##hY9hb4IwEIa/8ysaP1G5shZhE6H@kUsTWYBIsp4GJNNfz1o1W4Yu@3Jtnue99u54Oe0PlExT3bSsDQe@CVjXsqFEs@mb09gTGwJWaVsdwxYGVCZC1eR5DuJ6mGhAaXhhgWDUFQploHIEVMA@991Hw0jYUquNXeqkIF/GF53EATvDRVfvQ2g5@IN4UWu0HYVOcKFAGnSNcquJHXpmt1qWmkzRa0QrarBR7QPSRAqQHCAPyAE3Ap63Fxe9zT8uOzqFKKE3uOt35YIqWhg@HXvP2xDRABrDefBDROz2QFd@YwfZPOqRSGZQeprOH009lfNonGTAZJx5qYCtgM0bHVU3nzya@1TOPAuItdsje4DpW5y5aXC9SuPsdaav8C8p1N8uz@/PKvm09ftbsf7P@5vX0xc) (note that 1e999 is greater than float limit (~4e308?), so it's the same as float infinity)

Comment: @ASCII-only you ninja'd me doing it darn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87977/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-quintec).