# Diophantine Approximation: find lowest possible denominator to approximate within given precision

Tags: code-golf, math, number, rational-numbers, approximation

### Challenge

Given a number `x` and a precision `e`, find the lowest positive integer `q` such that `x` can be approximated as a fraction `p / q` within precision `e`.

In other words, find the lowest positive integer `q` such that there exists an integer `p` such that `abs(x - p/q) < e`.

### Input

- The pair `(x, e)` where `x` is a floating-point number, and `e` is a positive floating-point number.
- **Alternatively**, a pair `(x, n)` where `n` is a nonnegative integer; then `e` is implicitly defined as `10**(-n)` or `2**(-n)`, meaning `n` is the precision in number of digits/bits.

Restricting `x` to positive floating-point is acceptable.

### Output

The denominator `q`, which is a positive integer.

### Test cases

- Whenever `e > 0.5` ------------------------> `1` because `x` ≈ an integer
- Whenever `x` is an integer ----------------> `1` because `x` ≈ itself
- `(3.141592653589793, 0.2)` ------------> `1` because `x` ≈ 3
- `(3.141592653589793, 0.0015)` --------> `7` because `x` ≈ 22/7
- `(3.141592653589793, 0.0000003)` ---> `113` because `x` ≈ 355/113
- `(0.41, 0.01)` -------------------------------> `12` for 5/12 or `5` for 2/5, see Rules below

### Rules

- This is code-golf, the shortest code wins!
- Although the input is "a pair", how to encode a pair is unspecified
- The type used for `x` must allow a reasonable precision
- Floating-point precision errors can be ignored as long as the algorithm is correct. For instance, the output for `(0.41, 0.01)` should be `12` for 5/12, but the output `5` is acceptable because 0.41-2/5 gives 0.009999999999999953

### Related challenges

- [Find the simplest value between two values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38425/find-the-simplest-value-between-two-values)
- [Closest fraction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/closest-fraction)
- [Convert a decimal to a fraction, approximately](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221196/convert-a-decimal-to-a-fraction-approximately)

Comment: Given the test cases, [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A063673) is vaguely related.

Comment: For that kind of challenges, I believe that the consensus is that floating point precision errors can be ignored as long as the algorithm is correct. You may however want to add a note about that. For instance, most answers (including mine) are returning the `5` of `2/5` instead of the `12` of `5/12` for `(0.41, 0.01)` -- because `0.41-2/5` gives `0.009999999999999953`.

Comment: Thanks! I added a note. Also made me realise "Whenever e >= 0.5" should be changed to "Whenever e > 0.5" to be consistent with the strict < in the definition "abs(x - p/q) < e".

Comment: As a mathematician working in Diophantine Approximation, I approve of this challenge.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Xx bytes

*Note: this challenge is quite a good introductory-challenge for [R](https://www.r-project.org/), which is the 'language-of-the-month' for September 2020, so I've blanked-out my answer in the hope of encouraging some other golfers to have a shot at it in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), too...*

> 50 bytes

> `function(x,e,s=1:e^-1)s[(x-round(x*s)/s)^2<e^2][1]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc9NDoIwEAXgvaeYxE1rClh@gho5CYEEpWJjaE1bhCPoNb1IJagJCrP83rxJRtmSCVlzURipEntqxNFwKVBHGNEJ3bHcoVinqHOUbESJupXGnsa5v2e5n6U0G/fRlROKYQl0MdaAuNFU53d7ddeDx1Pv512hwWz4if2QxhH0Cs/HHeJoG268wfBPy/m/Cej7PrRSXTS03JxBsKow/MZANPWBKU3ASImtfQE)

Function with arguments x & error e.  Can handle negative x (even though not required for challenge)

---

*Note 2: dammit!  a port of [xnor's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210572/diophantine-approximation-find-lowest-possible-denominator-to-approximate-withi/210595#210595) is 6 bytes shorter still:*

> 44 bytes

> `function(x,e,s=1:e^-1)s[(x+e)%%(1/s)<2*e][1]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/hCoIwEAfw7z3FQQhbTd0U0SKfRAysVo1wCzfTR6jX7EVsGJKh9/F397/jqu7EpSqFLIyq0u5cy6MRSqKWcKJTtuV7l2GdoXbNseMg5mu8C1Y8z1g@TqK7IAzDEthirCHxoqnOz1r1aO/x1G19IyycbQ79MKBJBJbh/XoCozTeJH6P@C/n/q7ZlYCGv6FR1U1DI8wVJL8URjw4yLo88EoTMErhrvsA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
∞.Δ*`Dòα›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8vXNTtBJcDm86t/FRw67//6MN9AwMDE11jPUMTQxNLY3MTI1NLSzNLY1jAQ)

**Commented:**

```
          # implicit input                    [e, x]
∞         # in the list of natural numbers
 .Δ       # find the first that satisfies:    [e, x], q
   *      #   multiply                        [e*q, x*q]
    `     #   dump on stack                   e*q, x*q
     D    #   duplicate                       e*q, x*q, x*q
      ò   #   round to integer                e*q, x*q, round(x*q)
       α  #   absolute difference             e*q, abs(x*q - round(x*q))
        › #   is this larger?                 e*q > abs(x*q - round(x*q))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,e,q=1:(x+e)%(1/q)<e*2or-~f(x,e,q+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRSsMwFIbv@xQHRJJs2doky2qH9UXUi26e6GBrtzSDSqnX@pq@SE0C3m09EEg4/8cfvtOn@2hqNY6mPFTH7VsFHUd@LsWGdnNk91SkZ/aIM9nYxZehcTkXbHTYuhZKoAn4oVQtxUroQq610g9FXigO2VIzDsKfO9jirrq0CB38/nxDVcO@dviO9p8OaXEjvXctHsxUj7xBqikoy0T4X36FkzLNp9EwKrQKda1X69RvEpbYoIi8XGS@2hEO8SYUYYlpLDiO3gNElZvYF4waOnMsvk7WW6KG9G6AxRP07QC9ffaZEvB1IGz8Aw)

We want to check that \$x\$ is within \$\pm \epsilon\$ of a multiple of \$1/q\$, that is, it falls within the interval \$(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\$ modulo \$1/q\$. To do this, we take \$x+\epsilon\$, reduce it modulo \$1/q\$, and check if the result is at most \$2 \epsilon\$.

A same-length alternative using only `%1`, which might help with porting:

```python
f=lambda x,e,q=1:(x+e)*q%1<e*q*2or-~f(x,e,q+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRSsMwFIbv@xQHRJp02dYki7XD@iLqRTdPdDDbNcmgUuq1vqYvUpOAd1sPBBLO//GH7/Tp3ttGTpOujvXH7rWGniHrKr4l/QJp1t3yB8y6TLRm@aVJXC44nRxaZ6ECkoAfQuSKb7gqxZ2S6r4sSskgXynKgPtzAzvc12eL0MPvzzfUDRwah29o/umQ5lfSB2fxqOd6xBVSzkF5zsP/igucEOtiHg0jQyuXl3qVWvtNQhMTFKXPZ1Fs9imDeOMypYluDTiG3gNEldvYF4xqkjkaXyfjLRGdDm6E5SMMdoTBPPlMBfgypnT6Aw)

Comment: Did you mean *that* **it** *falls within the interval...*?

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 5 bytes

```
2$YQ&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30glMlDt/39jPUMTQ1NLIzNTY1MLS3NLYy4DPQMwMAYA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N9IJTJQ7X@ES1RFyH9jPUMTQ1NLIzNTY1MLS3NLYy4DPVMDQy4TIyDDAAqMuLApwy5qYGBoikMCBIwB).

#### Explanation

```
2$   % The next function will take two inputs
YQ   % (Implicit inputs: x, e). Rational approximation with specified tolerance.
     % Gives two outputs: numerator and denominator
&    % The next function will use its alternative default input/output
     % configuration
     % (Implicit) Display. With the alternative specification, this displays
     % only the top of the stack, that is, the denominator
```

### Manual approach: 17 bytes

```
`GZ}1\@:q@/-|>~}@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8E9qtYwxsGq0EFft8aurtbh//9oAz0DMDDWUTDWMzQxNLU0MjM1NrWwNLc0jgUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D/BParWMMbBqtBBX7fGrq7W4X@sS1RFyP9oAz1TA0MdBWM9QxNDU0sjM1NjUwtLc0vjWC6glAEUGOkomBiBRYxwKzU0xW@MMTZpAA).

#### Explanation

```
`       % Do...while
  GZ}   %   Push input: array [e, x]. Split into e and x
  1\    %   Modulo 1: gives fractional part of x (*)
  @:q   %   Push [0, 1, ... , n-1], where n is iteration index
  @/    %   Divide by n, element-wise: gives [0, 1/n, ..., (n-1)/n]
  -|    %   Absolute difference between (*) and each entry of the above
  >~    %   Is e not greater than each absolute difference? (**)
}       % Finally (execute on loop exit)
  @     %   Push current iteration index. This is the output
        % End (implicit). A new iteration is run if all entries of (**) are true;
        % that is, if all absolute differences were greater than or equal to e
        % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Denominator@*Rationalize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yU1Lz83My@xJL/IQSsIKJyfl5iTWZX6P6AoM69EwSE92ljP0MTQ1NLIzNTY1MLS3NJYR8FAzyiWC78CAwNDU8JqQMA49v9/AA)

All the credits go to @the default

Comment: Can you just do `Denominator@*Rationalize`? (I did not post it because I thought it's too long and I do not really like non-winning Mathematica answers) (it's a shame `Part` doesn't work on `Rational`s)

Comment: @thedefault. did you change your pronoun?

Comment: Not really, my username has been reset to the default (by the Stack Exchange Community Management Team™), so I set it to the default.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 38 bytes

Expects `(x)(e)`.

A port of [@xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210595/58563), which is significantly shorter than my original approach.

```javascript
(x,q=0)=>g=e=>(x+e)%(1/++q)<e*2?q:g(e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc1BDsIgEIXhvfcwmRFFGIqKkXqWpk5JTVPEGtPboyyNm77t9yfv3rybqX32j9dujDfOnc8wb5NX6Ovg2dcwC8Y16L0QCS@8oWs6B2DMbRynOLAcYoAOSJFCUFIpjbj6NU3SVAXtHxmpK20dHayxJ3d0pmS0LPte2aVlmUHMHw)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 46 bytes

Expects `(x)(e)`.

```javascript
(x,q=0)=>g=e=>((x*++q+.5|0)/q-x)**2<e*e?q:g(e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc1BDsIgEIXhvSeZAYsDFBUj9SxNpY1NU8Qaw8K7oyyNm77t9ydvbF/t0j1u92c1h6vPvcuQttERumZw3jUAiXEeuTBvwl2sEjKmzp75SzwN4DF3YV7C5MUUBuhBkSIEEkQScfNrUgldFzR/pIWspbFqb7Q52oPVJVPrsu@VWVuWacT8AQ)

We want to avoid using the lengthy `Math.round()` and `Math.abs()`. So we look for the lowest \$q>0\$ such that:

$$\left(\frac{\left\lfloor xq+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}{q}-x\right)^2<e^2$$

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>74</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>52</s></sup> 50 bytes

Saved <s>a</s> <s>4</s> 6 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
f=lambda x,e,q=1:not-x*q%1>e*q<x*q%1or-~f(x,e,q+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDRasMgFIbv8xQHxlBT00aty1KWvsi2i7TTtdAljVrICNn19pp7kUyF3bU5IBzx//jlO3@6Q9uIadLVqf7YvdXQU0W7im2a1mV92t2zrUq7p7i1JvvSOAYWjExOWWehApyAH4zFkq2ZLPmDFPKxLEpBIV9KQoH5cwc7ta8vVkEPvz/fUDdwbJx6V@afDml2I310Vp30XA@/QYo5KM9Z@F9xheN8VcyjYURoZeJar5Qr/5KQxARF6OXCi/UeUYgbE4gkujXgqPIeIKrcxL5gVOPUkXg7G28JazS4EbItDHaEwTz7TAXqdURk@gM)

Comment: Instead of testing `int(x*q)` and `int(x*q)+1`, you can just use `round(x*q)` and get rid of the `max`.

Comment: @ovs Had just realised that but was using `int(x*q+.5)` which is longer than `round` - thanks! :-)

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDRasMgFIbv8xQHdhHtTBO1NkshfZFtF6bVrtAmjRrICNn19pp7kUwDu2tzQFD8P/7Dd/t0H03Np0mXF3mtjhJ6okhb0p3ay8qiPjFNVx9Rv2px2uLGJF8azZFniienrLNQAorAD0J8TTdUFGwruHgp8oITyNYCE6D@PEGlDrKzCnr4/fkGWcO5duqkzD8d0vRB@uysuuilHvaA5EtQltGwX36HYyzNl9EwPLRSfq9XiNT/RDgyQVH81rF8c4gJzDfKYxzpxoAjynuAWeVu7gtGNVo5PL9uxltCOh7cCMkeBjvCYF59pgT1PsZ4@gM) by not using `q` for the final result.

Comment: @ovs Truely diabolical - thanks! :D

Comment: ... And a slightly different approach for [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDRasMgFIbv8xQHxlBT00aty1KWvsi2i7TTtdAljVrICNn19pp7kUyF3bU5IBzx//jlO3@6Q9uIadLVqf7YvdXQU0W7im2a1mV92t2zrUq7p7i1JvvSOAYWjExOWWehApyAH4zFkq2ZLPmDFPKxLEpBIV9KQoH5cwc7ta8vVkEPvz/fUDdwbJx6V@afDml2I310Vp30XA@/QYo5KM9Z@F9xheN8VcyjYURoZeJar5Qr/5KQxARF6OXCi/UeUYgbE4gkujXgqPIeIKrcxL5gVOPUkXg7G28JazS4EbItDHaEwTz7TAXqdURk@gM).

Comment: @ovs You've blown my mind - thanks! :)))))

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>63</s> <s>59</s></sup> 58 bytes

Saved a byte using [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s idea in his [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210595/9481)!!!

```c
i;f(x,e,q)float x,e,q;{for(q=0;fmod(x+e,1/++q)>2*e;);i=q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLfaoMwFMbv@xQHQUhqtEZrO8nszdhTrGWInnRCq/XPRZj46nPR6jq6XkxiSD5/3/mSg4l9TJK@z4QkiiErqTwVcQPjWrSyqEgZuUKei5QoCxlfWVZJd94SBRVZVIquz/IGznGWE7poF6Cfa4UG6@ZdvR0g0lLrO3zNg9DbBH7wFG5Dn8EwHqj/klxnzTtxn4ZzmutsBoYPkzdMrssDXQhtdztuZ/NwdlQXVA2ms1m7rkOjnOuwYIKTj7haQjVyrbFXr95ehS/6DQwGv/e@oR3XwxUVkCEky1NU2ueKafkMdfaJhSRzPF1NwvJHEWBZI03h2tnbfYdaU4dH4iDuAJwB/ANMl9bAz9UfIbUGxp@C3vRLpb9IYhBTMjAdDynYOzBTMOt9rrugGCCDmukujQkR1IfJ3i26/iuRp/hY9/bp/A0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔¹ζＷ›↔⁻∕⌊⁺·⁵×θζζθη≦⊕ζＩζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoIwEEX3nKLLaYIExKqEFdFoWGBYeIEKE2lSCrQFEy9fS3ThZjLv58@8puO6Gbh0rlTjbG9z/0ANE82Df@48F8aIp4IkJG9Pr05IJHDVyK0vFA8zyNkiVELNBs5iES3CRQ6Dhlr6JI5YSO6iRwPT@oHSdYZkWpeOUlLx8WcoVaOxR2Wx/bpqLZSFEzcW/GHuXBolu4Rl2z1L2TE7ZGkQR3GcMLdZ5Ac) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input \$ x \$ and \$ \epsilon \$.

```
≔¹ζ
```

Start off with \$ q = 1 \$.

```
Ｗ›↔⁻∕⌊⁺·⁵×θζζθη
```

Calculate \$ p = \lfloor 0.5 + q z \rfloor \$ and repeat while \$ | \frac p q - x | > \epsilon \$...

```
≦⊕ζ
```

... increment \$ q \$.

```
Ｉζ
```

Output \$ q \$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>84</s> <s>60</s> 52 bytes

*Saved a whopping 24 bytes thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)!*

```scala
x=>e=>1 to 9<<30 find(q=>(x-(x*q+.5).floor/q).abs<e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY69CsIwHMR3n@I/JooxaRq10hQEFwfxAcQhbVOohKQfUQris9eqi530puPux3FtpozqXXrRmYeDKi3ozmubt7CtKrhPbspAsYGdu6ZGg0y@3LHypbOnvfVnkH0nEy0TBt5BFMecQlHaHNUyQd0cddN6RgQmhXGuWdSYqLSNNe6rprTeWFQgTljIRBQsBRfraBVxjCgJMJ78QChl4h/qJT4CKQnZu2OjmA0/P7tD/Oif)

Comment: Surely since you're testing the floor & ceiling separately, and you know that floor<ceiling, you don't need either of the ```abs```?  Something [like this](https://tio.run/##jYpNCsIwGET3PcW3TARrYqxaaQqCGxfiAUQktilGYpLWKAH17PUHF7rSWc28ecdCaNHa7V4WHhZCGZDBS1MeYeocXKKz0FBNYGZPWy2B5x9t6byyZjU3fg28DTyXPL@og7ONh4Pwu3gTUfAW0ixjBCplSlTzPHQrbW2DQqfGvTqT10Iq/V7dkEl8a12jjNcGVYjFdECTtD9MWDJORynDiMR9jKMfCiE0@cd6hn2JJB7Q10cf@NbeAQ)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You're right, thanks!

Comment: Or maybe you could add 0.5 and just use the floor, [like this](https://tio.run/##jcrBisIwGATge5/iPybKxqQxaqUpCF48iA8gsqSaYiQmaRulUHz26u5JT7tzGma@9qisGnx50ccIW2Uc6C5qd2phFQL0yV1ZqJaw9rfSapDFW9uFaLzbb1w8gBw6WWhZ9OYafBPhquKZfCcMoocszzmFyrgTqmWhyhZ1X5X1vkHdqB4TgSc1zjV@DKExLlqHKsQJmzKRpTPBxSKbZxwjSlKMkz8IpUz8R/2Ef0BKpuz3Y6/5MTwB)?

Comment: Wow, that's even better! You saved me 24 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 52 bytes

Port of [xnor’s method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210595/95792)

```java
x->e->{int q=0;for(;(x+e)%(1./++q)>=e*2;);return q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY6xTsMwEIb3PIUXJJuSI04aIDLJhJAYmDoiBpM6kUNqJ86lahXl2YMrdYCpCG65k/77Pv2N3Muw2X4uZSuHgbxKbaagGz9aXZIBJfq1t3pLdj6gG3Ta1G/vRLp6YGQKGk/DiLqFajQlamvg@Xw8PllvUTfkNz8vBlWtXFGQylqSL4ewUGExaYOkzyNRWUcFPawUu6IcblernhW5uo4FE07h6AzpxbyIYHMcUO3Ajgidb4qtod4HsuvaI02Ar3maxXdpkj5k91nCzkEEMWN/h6OIp//jT5NcVESw5t8ofhHgkP5oeQLmYF6@AA)

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>83</s> 69 bytes

```java
x->e->{int q=0;for(;Math.abs(x-Math.ceil(x*++q-.5)/q)>=e;);return q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZAxb4MwEIV3foVHuykuDqEtojBVlTpkylh1cIihpo4N9hERIX47daoM2RK1t9xJ7753T9fwAw@b3fdcKu4cWnOpx6Dtt0qWyAEH3w5G7tDeC3gDVur64xNxWzuCxqDxNO1BKlr1ugRpNH07Dy@vxruIe3TLzrsGUQtbFKgyBuXzEBYiLEapAXV5lFXG4mzN4YvyrcND@DuWQio83C0WXUgT8tCRIhcZyayA3mrUZdOcBZujA7Gnpgfa@uigNPYHKG9bdcQxZSuWpMvHJE6e06c0JmchoktC/g5HEUv@x58qvmoR0RW7oNhVgPk/XaY8AVMwzT8)

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##pZCxboMwEIZ3nsIjLsXFIbRFLkxVpQ6ZMlYdHGKoqWODfUREKM9OnSpDtkTtLffr/vvuTtfyPY/b7fdcKe4cWnGpp6AbNkpWyAEHn/ZGbtHOG@EarNTNxyfitnEYTUHraTKAVKQedAXSaPJ2Fi@vxk8R9@iWnncNohG2LFFtDCrmMS5FXE5SA@qLhNXGhmzF4YvwjQvH@FfWyvjyeBdFfUQy/NDjshAMMytgsBr17DizYH1wIHbEDEA6fzsoHfoNhHedOoQpoUua5YvHLM2e86c8xWcjIQuM/w4nCc3@x58ivToiIUt6QdGrAPV/urzyBByD4/wD)?

Comment: @Arnauld That's funny, I just wrote the exact same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language 89 bytes

```
f[n_,e_]:=Denominator@Cases[{#,Abs[n-#]}&/@Convergents@n,x_/;x[[2]]<=e][[1,1]]
```

---

```
f[0.41,.01]
(* 5. *)
```

This uses the convergents as candidates for approximations.

```
pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028842
```

The first 8 convergents of pi:

```
Convergents[pi, 8]
(* {3, 22/7, 333/106, 355/113, 103993/33102, 104348/33215, 208341/66317, 312689/99532}*) 


f[pi, 0.01]
(* 7 *)

f[pi, 0.001]
(* 106 *)

f[pi, 0.00001]
(* 113 *)

f[pi, 0.0000001]
(* 33102 *)

f[pi, 0.0000000001]
(* 99532 *)
```

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XyPD1tA6PCMzJzXaMak4WllXo8zWOT@vLLUoPTWvBCigkxEbHZ2hrR0bqxlrp2wUa@2Smpefm5mXWJJf5FCmqfY/oCgzr0TBIT3aWM/QxNDU0sjM1NjUwtLc0lhHwUDPKJYLvwIDA0NTwmpAwDj2/38A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @J42161217 Post it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 58 bytes

```perl
sub f{grep{$p=$_[0]*$_;abs$p-int$p+.5<$_[1]*$_}1..1/$_[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVRRT8IwEH7nV1xwRqZjrB1lsjniD9A3jQ@EEMAOm@DWrMXMEN71b/pH5rVMSYRXEy7Levf1cndfvraSlytWrxWHO6F0HD9qsYKLTJRKXyQtgz9wg98XJQeNrkpHLKnVeg7ZZllyuXFk6kzHweTSmSazuXJkV@TakVc@u0GcGHxLfJ/0bLSts6LswDj0SZ@wIR2wkF0Po2HoQeBT2Fk6AjLx0DmDOV/MzBQVfH1@QAgnYC37P84gCAhrGERHGVDai06cgbHQakBC5HCgAWM93DkJBoHfJ3ZociQHGbBGA0IBjx3g4BTMeioKEBr22SBqTs7h/D@34OmF5/yNlyiBUDDLAa8YX2Jscv7oI7Tiq@z/GbgbS@L1veNUnsPxq6Sb3uIr8IsvC@2m2W7f3cMizwo3VbJEFlm7Ss@7NFAAHB1inUryhebPGDMMsYr12t6@kWdq7yru36c4Fso2bVJsn6S1rb8B)